# What phrase or expression is used to describe someone who speaks eloquently?

Tags: expressions, figures-of-speech

I have heard the phrase a few years ago and now I can't remember it.

It's a figurative phrase or expression used when someone has the skill of speaking fluently with a great lexicon, someone eloquent. It's not silver tongue. It goes more along the lines of someone that has the gift/touch of someone.

The first and only time I heard the phrase was from a video of someone one (can't remember who it was) during an interview and they were acknowledging their way of well speaking because they had the *insert phrase here*.

EDIT: I kept searching in Google using my keywords and 20 minutes after posting this I found it! It was **the gift of gab**.

Comment: The "gift of gab" can have a negative connotation, since "gab" means "to talk idly or incessantly, as about trivial matters" (the Free Dictionary by Farlex). An idle- and incessant talker is not necessarily eloquent, nor does he or she have a silver tongue. A person with the gift of gab is voluble but not necessarily eloquent. By the way, to tell someone "You have the gift of gab" is at least somewhat insulting!

Answer (score 0):

One who is *loquacious* speaks eloquently. As defined it means excessively talkative.

Edit: While looking you should check out usage of *Blarney* for ability to verbally smooth the way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Elliot! I've got good news! I kept searching in Google using my keywords and after 20 minutes after posting this I found it! It was the gift of gab.